# Unable to create a simple 3D box in P3D

Tags: java, intellij-idea, processing

I wanted to make a simple 3D box using the code below.....

```
public class Start extends PApplet {
    public void setup() {
        size(800, 600, P3D);
    }

    public void draw() {
        background(0);
        box(50, 40, 100);
    }

}
```

and I run into an exception. The error message is below:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/media/opengl/GLException
    at processing.opengl.PGraphicsOpenGL.createPGL(PGraphicsOpenGL.java:1744)
    at processing.opengl.PGraphicsOpenGL.<init>(PGraphicsOpenGL.java:518)
    at processing.opengl.PGraphics3D.<init>(PGraphics3D.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at processing.core.PApplet.makeGraphics(PApplet.java:1919)
    at processing.core.PApplet.size(PApplet.java:1771)
    at processing.core.PApplet.size(PApplet.java:1742)
    at Start.setup(Start.java:8)
    at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2361)
    at processing.core.PGraphicsJava2D.requestDraw(PGraphicsJava2D.java:240)
    at processing.core.PApplet.run(PApplet.java:2256)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.media.opengl.GLException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 15 more
    Exception in thread "Animation Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: javax/media/opengl/GLException
    at processing.core.PApplet.makeGraphics(PApplet.java:1944)
    at processing.core.PApplet.size(PApplet.java:1771)
    at processing.core.PApplet.size(PApplet.java:1742)
    at Start.setup(Start.java:8)
    at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2361)
    at processing.core.PGraphicsJava2D.requestDraw(PGraphicsJava2D.java:240)
    at processing.core.PApplet.run(PApplet.java:2256)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am using Java and Processing together with IntelliJ Idea.
Graphics Card might be the problem so here are specs:
Intel HD Graphics 4600

Sorry if I didn't give enough information, tried my best but I'm a bit new to stack and printing stack traces and all.

Comment: Question edited: code formatted, and Processing removed from the title as it is not needed there since you're using the [tag:processing] tag.

Comment: This is not a hardware problem, since it works from the Processing PDE. The problem is complaining about not being able to find a class, which means you're missing something in your classpath. What's on your classpath?

Answer (score 0):

I tried running your code. I also got an error except it said: `The public type Start must be defined in its own file`

So I removed the surrounding class declaration and it ran fine.

This is the code I ran (that worked)

```
public void setup() {
    size(800, 600, P3D);
}

public void draw() {
    background(0);
    box(50, 40, 100);
}
```

Note: I am running this in the default processing IDE, so I don't know if this is going to help.

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem. Am updating to import all library from processing 3 application folder to project structure, then fix it.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it after adding `jogl-all-natives-windows-amd64.jar` and `gluegen-rt-natives-windows-amd64.jar.  You'll find them in the` core/library` folder.